# How do I ask for pick up and drop off services from the hotel

Tags: phrase-request

I booked a hotel which offers complimentary pick up and drop off services. 
I'd like to know the English I need over the phone when I arrived at the train station where they can pick me up.

Also I'd like to know how to ask for the schedule for dropping off when I am about to check out. Like, can I say:

> I'd like to know what's the schedule of drop off like.

Also, how can I express the idea that at what time can they drop me off at the station. If I say

> Can you guys drop me off at the station at 5:00?

I feel like this could be understood as they would drop me off at that station at 5:00 or they would get me in the car at 5:00 and drive me to that station. If I want to express the latter, how should I phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for what happens after you get off your train, you can simply say:

> I am at the train station. How long will I have to wait for a ride back to the hotel?

However, if you want to ask about this ahead of time, you can ask:

> How can I arrange a ride to the hotel after I get off the train?

---

As for how to ask about getting dropped off, I'd start by asking:

> Do the shuttles run on a set schedule? Or can I arrange a drop-off?

If they tell you that drop-offs are arranged on an as-needed basis, you can ask:

> How do I *arrange* (or *schedule*) a drop-off?

Lastly, if you want to leave the hotel at 5:00, I think a good way to inquire about that would be:

> Can we leave for the station at five o'clock?

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. Another quick question related to asking for pick up services over the phone. What is the first sentence I should say over the phone? Like, "Hi, my name is ..., I am a tenant/ guest/ customer of your hotel."

Comment: @Joji - Use _guest_. Or you could just say, "I am staying at your hotel," or, "I have a reservation at your hotel."

Comment: Thank you!! just one last quick question, if I'd like to ask the front desk staff about getting dropped off, can I start by saying "Hi I'd like inquire about how to arrange a drop-off."

Comment: @Joji - That would sound quite normal to me.

Answer (score 0):

A car ride provided by a hotel between the hotel and an airport or train station is often called a *transfer*.

So you can say, "I'd like to arrange a transfer to the train station", or "Do you offer transfers to the train station?".

Comment: is this AE or BE?

Comment: @Joji, I hear it mostly in the context of international travel, so call it "world English".